azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (404) Resource not found
I'm new to programming.
I met a problem when loading DOCX, XLSX, and PPTX with AzureAIDocumentIntelligenceLoade
I have created Document Intelligence successfully and got an "endpoint" and "key".
However, when I try to load an Xlsx document through langchain_community in the Python environment, my computer reports as following:

azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (404) Resource not found Code: 404 Message: Resource not found

Here is my code snippet:
`file = "D:/Python/xuexisucai/LLM/Coffe list.xlsx"
endpoint = "https://xxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
key = "123456"
loader = AzureAIDocumentIntelligenceLoader(
api_endpoint= endpoint, api_key= key, file_path=file, api_model= "prebuilt-layout"
)
documents = loader.load()`

Which expert can come and help this newbie?


The error ResourceNotFoundError occurs due to invalid details Endpoint , Key and Document Path.

According to Document the Document Intelligence layout model offers support for analyzing XLSX files, ensuring accurate extraction of text, tables, figures, and hierarchical structures.

XLSX documents can be processed effectively with this model, requiring clear photos or high-quality scans for optimal results.


Development options include utilizing Document Intelligence Studio, REST API, and SDKs.

Output components include paragraphs, where text blocks like titles, section headings, and footnotes are extracted, alongside tables, which are parsed to determine column and row information.




Figures such as charts and images are detected, and sections within the document are identified, aiding in organization and comprehension. Additionally, the model can output extracted text in markdown format, facilitating integration with markdown-based workflows.


from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.documentintelligence import DocumentIntelligenceClient
from azure.ai.documentintelligence.models import AnalyzeResult

endpoint = "DOCUMENTINTELLIGENCE_ENDPOINT"
key = "DOCUMENTINTELLIGENCE_API_KEY"

document_intelligence_client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))

# Path to your XLSX file
path_to_xlsx_file = "C://Users//file_example_XLSX_101.xlsx"

# Open the XLSX file as a binary read mode
with open(path_to_xlsx_file, "rb") as f:
    poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document(
        "prebuilt-layout", analyze_request=f, content_type="application/octet-stream"
    )
    result: AnalyzeResult = poller.result()

    # Process the analysis result
    for page in result.pages:
        print(f"----Analyzing layout from page #{page.page_number}----")
        print(f"Page has Pageitems: {page.items} and page_number: {page.page_number}, ")

    

Output:

